# Metro style apps in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html

I was wondering if it is possible to create metro style apps (Html5 etc) for Windows 8 using templates for Visual visual studio 2010?

I know there is a download for Visual Studio Express 11.

TIA
JD

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 can not be used to create Metro style applications you need to use Visual Studio that came with the Windows Developer Preview.

Comment: Are you very sure about this?